# TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of null angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was implementing nested routing in my app, So I made nested routing module inside nested components then imports module and declare component

But getting error: Cannot read property 'form' of null.... I imported form module also.

Then I check PendingChangesGuard.canDeactivate (can-deactivate.guard.ts:17)

[image: But getting error: Cannot read property 'form' of null.... I imported form module also.]

[image: Then I check PendingChangesGuard.canDeactivate (can-deactivate.guard.ts:17)]

Comment: Can you show a component which is implementing the interface?

Comment: Reproduce the issue in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Defensive programming, you should check variable is null or undefined before using it.

```
import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'util';

if(!isNullOrUndefined(component) && component.form.dirty){
     // your code
}
```